# MVC Page Load instantiate several controllers with shared resources

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

I have detected, that during loading the main page several controllers are instantiated (I think because the main page is built from several parts). The controllers instantiate the API classes to query some data through them. I was wondering how and where I could share the same API class instance between them.

I can imagine such a code:

```
class HomeController : Controller
{
   private MyApi Api;
   public HomeController()
   {
     this.Api = get the pervious MyApi instance form somewhere
     if (this.Api == null) // 1st time
     {
         this.Api = new MyApi();
         put this instance to somewhere to share between controllers
     }
```

This "somewhere" is not a session, because next page load needs another MyApi instance. It must go to an object property which remains intact during the whole page load process, but is dismissed when the html result is generated. It must be really a simple thing, but I really don't know where it is :( Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using **Microsoft Unity Framework** in your application.

Using Unity Dependency Injector you will be able to inject instances of MyApi class into the any controller and avoid writing " if (this.Api == null) " these types of checks and also managing instances of it in some Session or Application level variables, which makes code dirty.

For this specific problem "It must go to an object property which remains intact during the whole page load process, but is dismissed when the html result is generated", You can configure Unity Injected object to have a life time of "**Scoped**". Meaning, the object will be created once per request.

Here's is a link on configuring Unity in an asp.net core application
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the @Html.Action(...) calls make different "scopes". I think it is nearly impossible to detect which controller actions can be "grouped" together (same user same page), and share resources between them. I thought these actions run on the same thread - but this is also not true.